# Flash: Debugging unexplained sprites?

Tags: flash, debugging

I've been trying to debug a strange white rectangle that is appearing in my Flash application:

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100813-tck3gimp3mhe9p1nssw26b1kdy.png](http://img.skitch.com/20100813-tck3gimp3mhe9p1nssw26b1kdy.png)

The standard debugging tools — binary search, breakpoints, `hg bisect` — have lead to dead ends.

Any suggestions tools I could use to debug this? Is there something like Firebug's inspector, which lets you mouse over HTML DOM elements to get information about them?

Answer (score 1):

Don't the mouse events bubble as they do in the DOM? Could you not use the Sprite (or lower) Prototype to debug print?

Comment: Not sure what you mean… Mouse events (and such) do bubble, but how would the Prototype help? I will try adding event listeners, though...